# Maven archetype for simple Servlet application

Tags: java, servlets, maven-2, maven-archetype

Is there a Maven 2 archetype for a simple Servlet (2.5) web application?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There **is** an archetype for **webapp**:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.acme \
                       -DartifactId=my-webapp \
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
                       -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This will generate the following structure:

```
$ tree my-webapp/
my-webapp/
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── resources
        └── webapp
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml
```

Where the web.xml is a Servlet 2.3 web.xml:

```
$ cat my-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml 
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

For a Servlet 2.5 web application, replace it with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

I don't know for NetBeans but Eclipse (more precisely M2Eclipse) relies on the `web.xml` to set the project facets (so you need to change the `web.xml` before the import, Eclipse won't update the web facet if you change the `web.xml` after the facts).

Comment: Might be useful to add a step like `mkdir -p my-webapp/src/main/java/com/acme/` and in that dir place a sample helloworld servlet.

Comment: Last lines are so true -- Eclipse (more precisely M2Eclipse) relies on the web.xml to set the project facets (so you need to change the web.xml before the import, Eclipse won't update the web facet if you change the web.xml after the facts).

Comment: This is outdated, set up for Servlet 2.3. Current spec is 4.0.1 and moving to 5 soon.

Answer (score 15):

## Archetype for Servlet 3

I have created simple archetype for creating Servlet 3 based webapps: https://github.com/maciejwalkowiak/servlet3-maven-archetype

Just clone it, install and generate project that uses Servlet 3, no XML, Tomcat7 ready (plugin included)

Comment: link no longer available

Answer (score 2):

you can start with

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

For a list of other archetypes,please refere to 
[archetypes list](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List)

Comment: -1 He did not ask how to create a Web project. He asked how to bump up the Servlet version (defaults to 2.3)

Comment: @Steve11235 Have you read the question or just the title! His answer correctly addresses the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updated archetype number.

*Note: By default archetype 'maven-archetype-webapp' generates Servlet 2.3 application. For upgrading to Servlet 2.5 kindly follow [post #1343356](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2783270/1343356) from Pascal Thivent*

---

Refer this link [Exclusive Maven Archetype List](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/06/exclusive-maven-archetype-list/) and follow this link for [How to use that archetype](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/06/how-to-generate-maven-based-java-j2ee-project-using-archetype/).

Frequently used archetype numbers are:

- 610 -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp (An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project)
- 600 -> org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-j2ee-simple (An archetype which contains a simplifed sample J2EE application.)

OR just use below handy maven command-

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.sample -DartifactId=servlet-app -Dversion=0.1-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: -1 He did not ask how to create a Web project. He asked how to bump up the Servlet version (defaults to 2.3)

Comment: this is his question "Is there a Maven 2 archetype for a simple Servlet (2.5) web application?" - kindly read before down vote. Arch id '200' indeed creates simple (servlet) web application.

Comment: @nanosoft - Updated post info, does it answer yours? kindly let me know.

Comment: @jeevatkm - U updated the archetype number.One of the number 610 doesn't exist in the link u posted and other one i.e 600 seems for org.xaloon.archetype:xaloon-archetype-wicket-jpa-spring. But yes the last lines in the link to correct post(that also u updated) is really useful.

Comment: @nansoft - My bad will update link content and revise this post. After that I will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Create maven project using maven-archetype-webapp archetype

command:
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.lei.webapp.quickstart  -DartifactId=webapp-quick-start   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp

- Add following dependency in pom.xml :

  javax.servlet
          servlet-api
          2.5

Answer (score 0):

I let the IDE (mine is Intellij IDEA) create the basic webapp structure for me.

Go to:

> File → New Project → create from archetype →
>   ...archetype-webapp

This will give the basic webapp structure.

Comment: This is outdated, set up for Servlet 2.3. Current spec is 4.0.1 and moving to 5 soon.