# Java Web Service Development - which libraries to take for simple setup?

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse

What Is a good combination of Web Server, Servlet Container (do I need this?) and Web Service Framework for Java?

Unfortunately I am a not experienced in Java development but have to do it for university (feel home with .NET and C#)

However I have to use Java and I have to create a Web Service. I feel both obstrained by the possibilites of libraries and terminologies.

I tried the combination of Tomcat6 and Axis2 under Eclipse 3.5.1. Java developer and manually installed the WPT part. I run into every possible error message.

I am looking for a dead easy yet supported library combination for Eclispe. Nothing rock solid for production scenario.

I am on Ubuntu 10.10 AM64 FWIM.

Comment: It's probably not going to get much easier then using Eclipse with Tomcat and Axis2. Did you configure Tomcat in Eclipse? (File > New > Server) Did you install the wsdl2java plugin? http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html

Comment: What has your teacher recommended you use?

Comment: Seconded on both questions. Though, I have a feeling Maven is going to open things up for you once you realize just how powerful it is. Suggesting a build system is only slightly tangential to your question, which is to get things up and running quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately our teacher recommended no technology regarding the Web Service part. The assignment is about Jena and reasoning, not about Web Services.

Comment: As it turns out I ran into an incompatibility between Eclispe 3.5.1 and Axis 1.5.3. According to a blog post the builder of Eclipse 3.5. doesn't copy to well with this version of Axis and after I used Axis2 1.4.1 everything is fine now. This would not have been a problem if I have used e.g. maven but as I am a Java noob I tried to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet the minimal set of requirements to get your code running in a web server, all you should need is Apache Tomcat. Though, you might want to consider a robust, annotation-driven framework to handle much of the configuration for you (ie, [Spring](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Spring_Framework)) and a build system (ie, [Maven](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Apache_Maven)) that handles dependency aggregation and compilation into a Web application ARchive (WAR file) that can be consumed by Tomcat, among the other highlights.

The added bonus of using Maven, by the way, is you'll be able to [generate a sample project from any of its servlet archetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782066/maven-archetype-for-simple-servlet-application) and get up and running quickly. It also provides a [handy Tomcat plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/) that makes deploying your latest development build painless (a la `mvn tomcat:deploy`). It's also [supported by Eclipse.](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Best of luck with your project, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For Webservices, I would say try REST based Jersey Framework [here](https://jersey.dev.java.net/use/getting-started.html), you already have HTTP concept and all it takes a couple of jars to download and there you go.