# Problems with servlets and maven

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

i am trying to build my first servlet using maven but don't know what i should add to the POM so the servlet

I have tried to add the below dependencies to the POM file (I found in one of the posts). The addition enables me to compile my servlet but when i try to run mvn package or to test my JUnits i am getting a ClassFormatError:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ClassFormatError: 
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract 
in class file javax/validation/Validation
```

The pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>java.net2</id>
  <name>Repository hosting the Java EE 6 artifacts</name>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
</repository>
```

can someone explain and guide?

Thanks
:-)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782066/maven-archetype-for-simple-servlet-application

Answer (score 1):

At the outset, you may want to follow Senthil's comment above.

As for the error, it is because the specified dependency only has the APIs (method definitions) and not the implementation.

Typically, the implementation is provided by the app server. Hence the application should work in an app server which implements Java EE 6 (like Glassfish).

`mvn package` should not give any error - it is the `test` phase before packaging which fails, which you can circumvent, if interested using `mvn package -DskipTests`.