# How to create Servlet 3.0 web application in maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, servlets, web-applications, maven-archetype

When I use eclipse to create webapp with maven using "maven-archetype-webapp", it creates only Servlet 2.3. How can I create Servlet 3.0?

Comment: Modern archetypes [here](https://code.google.com/p/generic-maven-archetypes/) or [here](http://maciejwalkowiak.github.io/servlet3-maven-archetype/)

Comment: Related: [*Maven archetype for simple Servlet application*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2782066/642706)

Answer (score 9):

There is still no good way of doing this.

Eclipse is parsing web.xml to indentify project's facet and therefore servlet version.

To achieve servlet 3.0 web app in eclipse follow these steps:

Using Eclipse only:

1. Create MVN project of maven-archetype-webapp 
   `New -> Project -> Mvn Project`
2. Replace web.xml file with new 3.0 version:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
         <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
       </web-app>
   ```
3. Close project and delete it from the workspace (don't delete files on the disk)
4. Delete .project and .classpath files and .settings directory from the project folder
5. Reimport project using `import -> Existing Maven Project`

---

Using MVN commandline + Eclipse

1. Create MVN project of maven-archetype-webapp

   ```
     mvn archetype:generate 
         -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.arechetypes 
         -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
         -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 
         -DgroupId=<my.groupid> 
         -DartifactId=<my-artifactId>
   ```
2. Replace contents of web.xml as in eclipse method point 2.
3. Same as point 5 from eclipse method.

Comment: Wow, This worked like a charm. I was having trouble loading apache CXF servlet. Doing this resolved my issue. Thanks Roman !. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks alot for this

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is to create a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse and then convert it to Maven project:

1. File -> New -> Dynamic Web Project
2. Right click on project name: Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

The project will be configured with the latest version of the servlet

Then add the servlet and jsp dependencies to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, after trying a lot of different ways to setup an eclipse web app to be deployed on aws, this is one of the most streamlined

Answer (score 0):

I usually create the 2.3 webapp then change it to 3.0 version.
The steps are approximatly:

1. In pom.xml: add maven-compiler-plugin configuration. source and target set to current java version (1.8), add servlet-api, jsp-api, jstl to dependencies.
2. Delete web.xml.
3. Open project properties (Alt+Enter on the project explorer)
4. Click on Project Facets
5. Uncheck checkbox for Dynamic Web Module, change version to 3.0
6. Check checkbox back. Click further configuration, change WebContent to src/main/webapp.
7. Generate Deployment Descriptor (in project explorer, right click Deployment Descriptor/Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub)