# How to create a skeleton of minimal Java application with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, servlets

For testing purposes, I need to create a very simple Java web application, which will contain only one servlet.

I want to be able to run this web app easily (e. g. by entering `mvn jetty:run`).

For a Vaadin application I used these calls:

```
1) mvn archetype:generate
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-clean
-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
-DgroupId=your.company
-DartifactId=project-name
-Dversion=1.0
-Dpackaging=war

2) mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Now I need analogous calls for creating a simple web app with just one servlet.

How can I do it (which Maven command/archetype can I use) ?

---

**Solution**

In order to create a skeleton of a web app, do following steps:

1) Run

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=ru.mycompany -DartifactId=mywebapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

2) Put

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
        <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

into the pom.xml file such that it looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mywebapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>mywebapp</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-jetty</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                <daemon>true</daemon>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-jetty</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

3) Run `mvn jetty:run -Djetty.port=PORT` and verify that you see a *Hello World!* lettering in the browser (*localhost:PORT/mywebapp*), where *PORT* is the port number you want Jetty to run on.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782066/maven-archetype-for-simple-servlet-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create archtype using `-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`

Also for `jetty:run` to work you need to update pom.xml with [jetty plugin](https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.pre5</version>
        <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>start-jetty</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                                <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                        <id>stop-jetty</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What repository is the Jetty plugin located in? I'm getting the error *No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Pisarenko\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]*.

Comment: jetty should be located in maven repo. You will need to udpated jetty plugin version to say 7.0.0.pre5 as I am not able to find 6.1.10

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the servlet in the web.xml.

And the maven configuration (pom.xml) like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8081</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you can start the web with the command:

```
mvn compile jetty:run
```

Comment: See my comment to Vinay's answer. `mvn jetty:run` is not working, I suppose it is necessary to add an additional repository.

Comment: The official maven plugin is here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/ 。So you do not need to change something with the default maven configurations.