# Maven archetype for simple Java Servlet 4 application

Tags: java, maven, servlets, project, maven-archetype

Basically the same as this Question, [*Maven archetype for simple Servlet application*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2782066/642706), but for the current generation of the [Java Servlet 4](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=369) standard.

Looking for a very simple project appropriate to quickly writing a demo Servlet or for starting a simple web app for real work.

- Needs to be able to package a [WAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)).
- No need for full [*Java EE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Enterprise_Edition) (now Jakarta EE) compatibility, nor even *Java EE Web Profile* compatibility. Just Servlet spec compatibility.

Comment: The last requirement may be a little complicated since Jetty 9 is a Servlet 3.1 container and Jetty 10, that will be a Servlet 4.0, is still under development (http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html ).  Honestly, nowadays I don't even bother with Maven archetypes. [Spring Initialzr](https://start.spring.io) can generate a Spring Boot 2.1 web project with embedded Tomcat 9 / Servlet 4.0 support in a matter of seconds. If you don't want Spring MVC just use `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` directly.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Thanks, fixed. I avoid *Spring*, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Basil, I understand. Unfortunately old school vanilla 
Web App archetypes for standalone Servlet containers have somewhat fallen out of favour. I haven't found any "modern" alternative to `maven-archetype-webapp` that doesn't assume either Java EE (e.g.: `webapp-javaee7`) or some kind of framework . You may need to build your own (it is not hard actually). I haven't tried myself but I would assume that `tomcat7-plugin` works with Tomcat 9 / Servlet 4.0 (it certainly works with Tomcat 8 / Servlet 3.1)

Comment: @BasilBourque Curious how this turned out for you?  I've spent a week chasing this  and have settled on https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven which seems overkill.